# Where to place domain services in AxonIQ

Tags: axon

I have a user aggregate which is created using CreateUser command which consists of aggregate identifier and username.

Along with that i have domain service that communicates with mongo db and checks if username exists, if not it puts it there.
eg registerUsername(username) -> true / false whether it registered it or not

My question is, would it be good idea to create command handler on top of the user aggregate that would handle the CreateUser command and whether it has username or not will dispatch proper commands/events? like so:

```
@Component
class UserCommandHandler(
    @Autowired
    private val repository: Repository<User>,
    @Autowired
    private val eventBus: EventBus,
    @Autowired
    private val service: UniqueUserService
) {

@CommandHandler
fun createUser(cmd: CreateUser) {
    if (this.service.registerUsername(cmd.username)) {
        this.repository.newInstance { User(cmd.id) }
                .handle(GenericCommandMessage(cmd))
    } else {
        this.eventBus.publishEvent(UserCreateFailed(cmd.id, cmd.username))
    }
}
}
```

This question is not necessarily related to the set uniqueness in ddd but more of a question where should i put dependency of domain services? I could probably create user registration saga and inject that service inside saga but i think saga should only rely on command dispatching and not have any if/else logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the place to put your domain service depends on the use case at hand.
I typically try to have domain service do virtual no outbound calls to other services or databases, at all.

The domain service you're now conceiving however does exactly that to, like you're point out, solve the uniqueness issue.
In this situation, you could likely come by with the suggested approach.

You could also think of introducing a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` (or even fancier, a `HandlerEnhancerDefinition` as described [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/handler-enhancers)), specifically triggering on the create command and performing the desired check.

If it would be domain service like I depicted mine just now (e.g. zero outbound calls from domain service), then you can safely wire it in your command handling functions to perform some action.

If you're in a Spring environment, simply having your domain service as a bean and providing it as a parameter to your message handling function is sufficient for Axon to resolve it for you (through the means of `ParameterResolvers`, as described [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/parameter-resolvers)).

Hope this helps you out @PolishCivil!